# Telegram удаляет часть данных команды

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Пишу бота на python (aiogram) где в стартовой команде при передачи  `/start join_to_room-[ТЕХТВBASE64]` выполняется подключение к комнате. Где в base64 храню индикатор комнаты.

Если отправлять команду напрямую все происходит как надо.

Если перейти по ссылки `https://t.me/[ИМЯБОТА]?start=join_to_room-[ТЕХТВBASE64]` с телефона все работает, бот получает такой текст: `/start join_to_room-Q294Z2lmODMzNw==`

Но при переходе по этой же ссылки с ПК, бот получает только `/start join_to_room-Q294Z2lmODMzNw`

Как исправить этот момент? Чтобы бот не терял данные.

Comment: и проблема только с K версией web tg